# Where do I get source code for the Java APIs?

Tags: java

I want to know where are the java API's stored. I use openJDK 7. I want to edit some of the code of a class to suit my needs and therefore I want to know where are these API's stored. Can anyone please answer this question?

Comment: So you're looking for the source code, not the API documentation? Wouldn't it make more sense to just extend the class in question?

Comment: I want to change the source code only .... i know to extend but i want to change the source code

Comment: Do not edit code in the Java API - it will make your installation non-standard.  Instead learn how to create subclasses and override the methods you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the source code, run (as a regular user, not root)

```
apt-get source openjdk-7-jre
```

It will download the source tree used to generate all the openjdk-7 packages. It downloads it to your current directory, so you may want to run something like `mkdir -p ~/src && cd ~/src` first.

The compressed archive `jdk-dfsg.tar.gz` at the root of the source tree appears to contain all the standard classes.

You might need to enable source code repositories:

- [How do I enable the source code repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158871/how-do-i-enable-the-source-code-repositories/158872#158872)

Comment: its coming as "E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"       Can you please suggest some links ??

Comment: @PranitBauva make sure each `deb`-line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` also has an identical (apart from the first word) `deb-src`-line. By default, all the standard repositories should have this, so I'm guessing you've modified your `/etc/apt/sources.list` at some point.