# How do I enable the source code repositories?

Tags: repository, software-sources

I need to install build-dependencies of something, how do I ensure the source code section of my software sources is enabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch the software center and select software sources:

[image]

In the software sources make sure "Source Code" is checked:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can enable source code repositories by uncommenting (removing `#`'s) `deb-src` repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
sed -i '/deb-src/s/^# //' /etc/apt/sources.list && apt update
```

If you want to disable source code repositories, you can comment it back

```
sed -i '/deb-src/s/^/# /' /etc/apt/sources.list && apt update
```

Comment: NB: You should follow that with an apt-get update otherwise this is not taken into account

Answer (score 4):

The default archive repositories have the source archives enabled as well as the binaries. Also, adding any PPAs with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/archive` should enable the source and binary archives both.

To verify, you can check in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and in the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, to ensure the `deb-src` lines for each `deb` archive line, are there. Also, in the `Software Sources` properties dialog, you can check that the `Source code` option is checked on the `Ubuntu Software` tab, and that there are corresponding `Source` entries for the `Binaries` entries, in the list of additional sources under the `Other Software` tab.