# How do I open C libraries and functions implementations?

Tags: programming, c

I am having a problem that I cannot browse the header files /libraries to  get the implementation of the C functions like mssget, msgsnd, shmat etc.

How should I open these files?

Comment: If these are binary files, you can't open them. Header files can be opened using gedit

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the `sys/msg.h` header file specifically, then it should be provided by the `libc6-dev` development package

First make sure that the package is installed, either via the Software Center application or from a terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

after which you should be able to browse the header file at

```
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/msg.h
```

(for 32-bit systems) or

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/msg.h
```

(for 64-bit systems).

---

To see the actual implementation of a library function, you will need to download the corresponding source code package: first, you will need to enable the relevant source repository (see [How do I enable the source code repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/158871/178692) if you don't know how to do that) and then, for example, in a directory of your choice

```
apt-get source libc6-dev
```

will download, unpack, and patch the source tarball into that directory (in this case, it will pick 'eglibc' as source package instead of 'libc6-dev'). However `msgget` and `msgsnd` appear to be only stub functions - I don't know enough about Linux IPC to advise you beyond that.

Comment: i saw these header files
i thought id see implementation of the C
functions like mssget, msgsnd,
shmat 
is it possible??

Comment: @NourMalkawi I have added information about obtaining the source code implementation