# Incorrect RAID size

Tags: raid

If anyone could offer any advice it would be much appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS server with 9 x 3TB WD Red hard drives in a RAID 5 configuration, using MDADM.

Is there any reason why I am seeing a difference in total RAID size capacity? I have attached some screen grabs with hopefully the correct information. If im missing anything please let me know.

Many Thanks.....

[image: File System Mount]

[image: MDADM Settings]

[image: lsblk command]

```
*df -T /srv/RAID
Filesystem     Type   1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md127     ext4 20428278764 16279337724 4148924656  80% /srv/RAID*
```

---

```
*/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Jul 23 20:38:24 2018
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 23441080320 (22355.16 GiB 24003.67 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930135040 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
      Raid Devices : 9
     Total Devices : 9
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent
     Intent Bitmap : Internal
       Update Time : Sun Mar 10 10:31:32 2019
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 9
   Working Devices : 9
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0
            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K
Consistency Policy : bitmap
              Name : kenny:RAID  (local to host kenny)
              UUID : d293081d:91d806d2:d70f301d:a4023e4a
            Events : 45623
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      144        0      active sync   /dev/sdj
       1       8      128        1      active sync   /dev/sdi
       2       8      112        2      active sync   /dev/sdh
       3       8       96        3      active sync   /dev/sdg
       4       8       48        4      active sync   /dev/sdd
       5       8       32        5      active sync   /dev/sdc
       6       8       16        6      active sync   /dev/sdb
       7       8        0        7      active sync   /dev/sda
       8       8       64        8      active sync   /dev/sde*
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Rather use formatting styles to highlight e.g shell output. Please also add the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md127` and `df -T /srv/RAID`.

Comment: Could you please specify what size differences you are talking about ?

Comment: The file system shows - 19.03TB & The RAID shows 21.8TB.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll get on it as soon as I get home. I noticed the issue when I added the 9th hard drive. I expanded the RAID (which grew in size) once completed but the file system size didn’t seem to change.

Comment: In that case you also have to resize the filesystem. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/779754/how-do-i-resize-an-ext4-partition-beyond-the-16tb-limit for more information.

Comment: I resized the file system (sudo resize2fs -p /dev/md127) and it worked perfectly. Now have 21.7TB. Really appreciate your help. Thank you