# Unable to resize partition beyond 16TB limit

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount

Following this guide: [How do I resize an ext4 partition beyond the 16TB limit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779754/how-do-i-resize-an-ext4-partition-beyond-the-16tb-limit)

I have done

`sudo lvextend -l +3145725 /dev/densrv1-vg/data
sudo resize2fs /dev/vgdata/lvdata`

I have unmounted my vggroup with **sudo umount -l /dev/vgdata/lvdata**

When ran **sudo ./resize2fs -b /dev/vgdata/lvdata**

I get the error:

```
resize2fs 1.44.2 (14-May-2018)
./resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/vgdata/lvdata
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Comment: I believe the order to be:  change partition size, "pvresize",  "lvextend -r". The -r activates "resize2fs".

Comment: thanks, so "sudo pvresize /dev/vgdata/lvdata" then "sudo lvextend -r /dev/vgdata/lvdata"?

Comment: Yes that looks good to me.

Comment: Unfortunately got an error: `sudo pvresize /dev/vgdata/lvdata
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/vgdata/lvdata".
  0 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
`

Comment: what does `pvs`  show? Ill be gone in 10 minutes so hope we can fix this before that ;-)

Comment: ` PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
  /dev/sda5  template-vg lvm2 a--  59.52g 12.00m
  /dev/sdb   vgdata      lvm2 a--   5.00t     0 
  /dev/sdc   vgdata      lvm2 a--   2.00t     0 
  /dev/sdd1  vgdata      lvm2 a--  10.00t     0 
  /dev/sde1  vgdata      lvm2 a--   5.00t     0 `

Comment: I've ready run the lvextend command, I'm getting stuck on the resize bit

Comment: @GodAtum as Rinzwind mentioned, if you have already run the lvextend command, it should have resized filesystem as well. What filesystem does your lvdata logical volume has? Manually running resize2fs is failing because /dev/vgdata/lvdata is already mounted. It will succeed if you umount it first.

Comment: It didn't resize it beyond 16TB. And as mentioned in my OP I unmounted it but still got an error.