# What does the "Source" field in "dpkg-query -W" output mean?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

For example, using this command:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}  -  ${Source}\n' | grep bind9
```

I get the following output on my machine:

```
bind9-host  -   bind9
bind9utils  -   bind9
dnsutils  -   bind9
libbind9-90  -   bind9
libdns100  -   bind9
libisc95  -   bind9
libisccc90  -   bind9
libisccfg90  -   bind9
liblwres90  -   bind9
```

does this mean all of these packages are compiled from a single `bind9` source package? could anybody explain more inner working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Source` field comes from from the `debian/control` file of a Debian package archive (`.deb`), it is assigned to the name of the package containing the source code for that specific package. The name of this field is really upto the developer/maintainer, sometimes the `deb` is part of a bigger source (this is happening in the case of `bind9` in your example), sometimes comes with a different name, sometimes same as the `deb` package name.

From a user's perspective, you can download any source package with ([assuming you have enabled the source repositories (`deb-src`)](https://askubuntu.com/q/158871/216503)):

```
apt-get source <deb-package-name>
```

So you just need to insert the correct `deb` package name, `apt` would pick the correct source package name from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.